# C, first member of struct

Tags: c

I have yet another newbie C question:
Why does the first member of a struct return an adress not similar to the structs own pointer-adress when not initialized?

Example:

```
struct Metadata {
    int message_ID;
    //other members...
    //...
};

struct Metadata* baseMetadataPtr = (struct Metadata*) malloc(sizeof(struct Metadata)*100);

printf("baseMetadataPtr: %d\n", baseMetadataPtr);
//consoll says "baseMetadataPtr: 2636496"

printf("baseMetadataPtr->message_ID: %d\n", baseMetadataPtr->message_ID);
//consoll says "baseMetadataPtr->message_ID: 2621636"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO..you can format the code in your questions using 1010 button at the top.

Comment: Style detail: if your `printf` supports it, use `%p` as the print specifier for pointers rather than an integer specifier like `%d`.

Answer (score 8):

Your second `printf` call is wrong.  It should be:

```
printf("baseMetadataPtr->message_ID: %p\n", &baseMetadataPtr->message_ID);
//         need to use %p for pointer ^     ^ need unary-& operator
```

As written right now, the integer value of `message_ID` is being  printed.  You need to take the address of `baseMetadataPtr->message_ID`.  Also note that if you want to print a pointer, you should use the `%p` format specifier, not `%d` (which prints an integer).

The address of the first data member of a struct-type object will always be the same as the address of the struct-type object itself.  This is guaranteed because no padding is permitted at the beginning of a struct (padding is permitted between data elements or at the end of the struct, though).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. But what are the value written to consoll when &-operator isn't used?

Comment: Err..`message_ID` is not being interpreted as a pointer until he uses the `%p` specifier. Right now `baseMetadataPtr` is being interpreted as a decimal integer...

Comment: @DoggyDoo:  It is whatever garbage data was in the block of memory to which the pointer returned from `malloc` points.

Comment: For extra conformance, cast every pointer to `(void *)` when printing with `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

I like drawings. They help me "see" stuff

```
struct Metadata *baseMetadataPtr;
baseMetadataPtr = malloc(100 * sizeof *baseMetadataPtr);
```

With that, and assuming a linear memory (the boxes below), and ignoring the space requirements for the different objects, we have

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|...|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|...
   ^^^^^^^ baseMetadataPtr
  (of type (struct Metadata *))

   ******* ===========================>
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|...|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|...
   ^^^^^^^ baseMetadataPtr             ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^ ...
  (of type (struct Metadata *))        *baseMetadataPtr (struct Metadata)
                                               *(baseMetadataPtr+1)
                                                      baseMetadataPtr[2]
```

And, zooming in on the part on the left

```
   *baseMetadataPtr
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|...
   ^^^ Message_ID (type (int))
       ^^^^^^^ Message_Len (type (size_t))
               ^^^^ ... other members, followed by another object of type (struct Metadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints the memory address of the pointer:

```
printf("baseMetadataPtr: %d\n", baseMetadataPtr);
```

and this prints the memory address of the variable inside the struct:

```
printf("baseMetadataPtr->message_ID: %d\n", &baseMetadataPtr->message_ID);
```

And that's why they are not neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

`baseMetadataPtr->message_ID` prints the *value* of the variable `message_ID`. Since you have not initialized it, it is containing garbage. To print its address you need to do `&baseMetadataPtr->message_ID`. Also, you need to use the format specifier `%p` to print pointer values.

Answer (score 0):

The first printf() prints the current value of the pointer, IE, what address it is pointing.

The second printf prints the value of the Metadata member message_ID.

To get what you want, try: printf("baseMetadataPtr->message_ID: %d\n", &baseMetadataPtr->message_ID);